# Show post excerpt

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to show several post excerpt, so I create function

```
function my_excerpt($limit) {
    $excerpt = explode(' ', get_the_excerpt(), $limit);
    if (count($excerpt)>=$limit) {
        array_pop($excerpt);
        $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt).'...';
    } else {
        $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt);
    }
    $excerpt = preg_replace('`[[^]]*]`','',$excerpt);
    return $excerpt;
}
```

and I use it:

```
<?php  echo bereza_excerpt(35); ?>
```

but I have problem - I cant save post formatting.

Is it possible to recreate this function and save text formatting in post excerpt?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to limit the number of words of your excerpt to echo, I'd recommend you to use [`wp_trim_words`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_words).

> This function trims text to a certain number of words and returns the trimmed text.

Try:

```
<?php
echo wp_trim_words( get_the_excerpt(), 35, '…' );
```

**Update:**

Ops! I missed the *keeping the format* part.